# route is not updated when parameters change

Tags: angular

I call the same component in my angular app with different parameters but the `ngOnInit` is called only once.
How can I solve this?
The purpose is that different data is shown depending the parameter

```
const routes: Routes = [{
        path: 'overviewscorings',
        component: MobileSessionOverviewComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full'
        ];
```

Template :

```
<ul class = "dropdown-menu">
     <li>  <a[routerLink] = "['/overviewscorings']"[queryParams] = "{sessionType : 'CHAR'}"> Characteristics </a>  </li>
     <li>  <a[routerLink] = "['/overviewscorings']"[queryParams] = "{sessionType : 'BOL'}"> Bolters </a>  </li>
     <li>  <a[routerLink] = "['/overviewscorings']"[queryParams] = "{sessionType : 'GAP'}"> Gap </a>  </li>
</ul>
```

Component :

```
export class MobileSessionOverviewComponent implements OnInit {

fieldMobileSessions: FieldMobileSession[] = [];
selectedItems:
FieldMobileSession[] = [];
sessionType: string;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route
    .queryParams
    .map(params = params['sessionType'])
    .subscribe(stats = this.sessionType = stats);
    console.log('type ' + this.sessionType); // let fieldMobileSessions = fieldTrialDb.fieldMobileSessions;

    this.find();
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('init');
    //this.load().subscribe(s =this.fieldMobileSessions = s);
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) = {
            this.sessionType
        })

}
```

Comment: all you need to know is located here : https://angular.io/guide/router#observable-parammap-and-component-reuse . Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can get queryParams by subscribing route.queryParams in this way,

```
sessionType: string;
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}

ngOnInit(){
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.sessionType = params['sessionType'];
    });
}
```